# setInterval Doesn't Increase var Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code should change the #magia div's content every three seconds but it doesn't change it.

```
$(function(){
    var NArray = -1;
    var ringraziamenti = ["", "Thanks", 
    "You saved my Website", 
    "Now you can use it, and try to find all the hidden tresure that there are", 
    "Good Luck"
    ];
    $("#Save").click(function(){
            setInterval(function(){
            NArray = NArray + 1;
    $("#magia").html(ringraziamenti[NArray]);
  }, 3000);
}
);
});
```

Comment: jQuery *is* Javascript..

Comment: `$(Modify1(){` thats invalid syntax, you should have an error on your console saying so

Comment: Check the console for errors. I can see at least 2; the random use of `Modify1()` and your `click()` handler is missing a closing `)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes they were errors that I made rewriting the code but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What on Earth are `Modify1` and `Intervallo`?  Are you looking for the `function` keyword?:

```
$(function() {
    //...
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#Save").click(function() {
            //...
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

---

**Edit:** Additionally, what is your interval *actually doing*?

> This code should change the #magia div's content every three seconds

Well, no.  All it does is set a click handler every three seconds.  The handler doesn't get invoked until the element is clicked.  Don't you want to *perform the action* every three seconds?  Remove the click handler:

```
setInterval(function() {
    NArray = NArray + 1;
    $("#magia").html(ringraziamenti[NArray]);
}, 3000);
```

And if you don't want to set the interval until after the element is clicked, wrap *that* in the click handler:

```
$("#Save").click(function (){
    setInterval(function() {
        //...
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: yeah thanks but it still doesn't work

Comment: @PeppedocBrown: Maybe you can be more specific?  I can't see your screen from here.

Comment: i've corrected the code that had posted

Comment: @PeppedocBrown: The code in the question is still incorrect.  `Modify1` and `Intervallo` aren't valid keywords.  They should be removed.  Take a look at the code in this answer for an example.  (Note: It's *very likely* that the browser's JavaScript console is pointing out the errors in your code.  It's generally a good idea to look at that.)

Comment: no in the console there are no errors and i used also jshint. Modyfy1 and Intervallo are after the keyword function so those should be the names of the functions

Comment: @PeppedocBrown: Naming functions in that context is invalid.  There's no *reason* for them to have names.  Take a look at the answer I posted.  It's... not a particularly long read.

Comment: i read it and i've also tried as you said but it doesn't work

Comment: @PeppedocBrown: Can you update the question to include the updated code and explain further what "it doesn't work" means?  When you debug it, where/how *specifically* does it fail?  I can't stress enough the fact that *I can't see your screen from here*.

Comment: Here it is as you asked

Comment: @PeppedocBrown: I've updated the answer.  The code technically *works* in that it's adding a click handler every 3 seconds.  So after three seconds, you can click the element and see the change.  But you *probably* want to only add the click handler once and change the element itself after three seconds?

Comment: I would that When a person click on that span "#Save" begin the function that every 3 seconds increases be Value of NArray by 1

Comment: @PeppedocBrown: The code you have, once corrected as per this answer, would do exactly that.

Comment: Anyhow it's not working @David. As you can see i've edited code as you told me but it isn't working

Comment: @PeppedocBrown: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/43vzgn7v/  Maybe you can be more specific about what "not working" means?  When you debug it, where *specifically* does it fail?

Comment: WTH I don't know why, but in JSFiddle it works but in chrome no @David. Anyhow I think that it's a stupid error thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code doesn't ever actually execute the line `NArray = NArray + 1;`

`$("#Save").click(function(){})` binds a click event to the `#Save` element, so your interval is reassigning that click function every 3000 ms. None of the actions inside of that click function will get executed until someone actually clicks on that `#Save` element.

Your interval function should look like this:

```
setInterval(function (){
  NArray = NArray + 1;
  $("#magia").html(ringraziamenti[NArray]);
 }, 3000);
```